# Work and Time proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If it takes "$x$", "$a$" days more to complete a work than the time taken by $(x + y)$ to do the same work and if it "$y$", "$b$" days more than the time taken by $(x + y)$ to do the same work, then $(x + y)$ do the work in $\sqrt{ab}$.

Please help me out in proving this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote with $n$ the days that $x$ and $y$ together need to complete the task. We are asked to show that $n=\sqrt{ab}$.

By the information given, $x$ needs $n+a$ days and $y$ needs $n+b$ days. This means that on each day $x$ completes $\dfrac1{n+a}$ of the task and $y$ completes $\dfrac1{n+b}$ of the task. Hence, when $x,y$ work together they complete on each day $$\frac1{n+a}+\frac{1}{n+b}=\frac{2n+a+b}{(n+a)(n+b)}$$ of the task. Since, they both together need $n$ days (by assumption) to complete the task, we have that \begin{align}n\cdot\frac{2n+a+b}{(n+a)(n+b)}=1&\implies 2n^2+n(a+b)=n^2+n(a+b)+ab\\[0.2cm]&\implies n^2=ab\overset{n>0}\implies n=\sqrt{ab}\end{align}

Comment: n*(2n+a+b)/((n+a)(n+b))=1, is it because we are considering work done as 1? Please let me know.

Comment: @AnshuMishra Yes, exactly. The whole work is denoted with $1$.